# How to redirect all/any page request on a site to a certain static page on same site

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, httpd.conf

I need every page request on a site -- 200, 404, etc. -- to land at a fixed page on the site, in this case `index_new.php`.

I've tried other SO and ServerFault answers and I continue to get an endless redirect loop.

**Here's my code in httpd.conf:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName my.example.com
    ServerAlias *.my.example.com
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index_new.php
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index_new.php [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

**Notes:**

1. the site's `.htaccess` file is empty
2. the "`index_new.php`" page is static with no PHP header("location:") internal redirects, etc.
3. I have restarted apache

Comment: The rule looks good, you might omit the RewriteCond and shorten it to `RewriteRule !^/index_new.php$ /index_new.php [R,L]`. Never test with [R=301](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153262/tips-for-debugging-htaccess-rewrite-rules/9204355#9204355)

Comment: Thanks @OlafDietsche. But your answer still results in `my.example.com redirected you too many times.` in my Chrome browser (not that the browser has anything to do with it -- merely showing you the format of the resulting message).

Comment: I just tried this locally and both, your version and mine, work properly. Maybe there's something else.

Comment: Ok thanks @OlafDietsche. I'll have a look around.

Comment: I think the problem was that there is a css stylesheet `<link>`'d in the `<head></head>` container. Once I `RewriteCond`'d it I was good to go.

Answer (score 0):

A Negative lookahead should do, and can easily be done with a single line with RedirectMatch instead of using mod_rewrite:

```
RedirectMatch permanent ^/(?!index_new.php).* /index_new.php
```

Clear your browsers cache and/or try with `curl -I http://my.example.com/wahtever` to make sure it is working

For sanity specify documentroot in the virtualhost and a directory entry to allow access (Require all granted / Allow from all depending on the version) and since you are not using .htaccess (btw congratulations! you are one of the few doing things right from the start), set the directory of the DocumentRoot with "AllowOverride none" just to be safe.